# Problem with Xdebug, WSL, VSCode; Exception still occurs

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug

I have a problem with Xdebug. When I start debugging suddenly every 30 seconds VSCode shows me this exception located in `vendor` (I also set ignore path in `launch.json`):

[image]

I want to disable this exception tracing.

Note: I use VSCode, Xdebug and WSL

As you can see, I disabled all breakpoints except one that I need but the problem still continues.

This is my launch.json

```json
{
  "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "port": 9003,
  "ignore": ["**/vendor/**"]
}
```

Also my php.ini Xdebug settings:

```ini
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.remote_autostart = "On"
xdebug.remote_enable = "On"
xdebug.log_level=10
xdebug.show_error_trace=0
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
```

I’ve tried everything to fix this problem, but could not find a solution. I’ve tried changing properties in `php.ini`, `launch.json` but without success.
When I try to debug my code and suddenly in the middle of debugging VSCode sends me to this screen without any warning, making debugging very useless.